# Something Aspected-Oriented in Javascript

Tags: javascript, aspect

So, i made this code to help me add functions after or before other functions, but i couldn't figure out a better way to do that, i had to use eval() and that is really not a good practice. At first, i tried to do something like:

```
Function.prototype.append = function(fn){
    eval("this = function(){ ("+this.toString()+").apply(this, arguments); fn.apply(this, arguments); }");
}

hello = function(){
    console.log("hello world!");
}

hello(); // hello world!
hello.append(function(){
    console.log("bye world!");
});
hello(); // hello world! bye world
```

but it didn't work since the function can't change itself. So i did this:

```
Aspects = new Object();

Aspects.append = function(aspect, fn){
    eval(aspect + " = function(){ ("+eval(aspect + '.toString()')+").apply(this, arguments); fn.apply(this, arguments); }");
}

Aspects.prepend = function(aspect, fn){
    eval(aspect + " = function(){ fn.apply(this, arguments); ("+eval(aspect + '.toString()')+").apply(this, arguments); }");
}

hello = function(){
    console.log("hello world!");
}

hello(); // hello world!

Aspects.append('hello', function(){
    console.log("bye world!");
});

hello(); // hello world! bye world!
```

i don't want to work with objects or anything, i just want to add more code after or before my already declared function

Comment: Also note your relying on `Function.prototype.toString` to return something sensible, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a utility library called [fcombine](https://github.com/Raynos/fcombine) which supports

```
f1 = fcombine.pre(new_function, f1);
f1 = fcombine.post(f1, new_function);
```

The reason your code is ugly is because your not returning the new function.

The problem with your code is also that it uses `eval` and tries to do too much magic. The whole idea of passing in a string of a variable name then evalling that is absolutely horrible.

You can quite easily write

`hello = Aspects.append(hello, new_function);`

As demonstrated by `fcombine.post`

Comment: thanks, yeah i think i will have to give up some magic and return the new function. Your library seems very useful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

what about this,

```
function fnAppend(old_fn_name, new_fn){
    var old_fn = window[old_fn_name];
    window[old_fn_name] = function(){
        old_fn();
        new_fn();
    }
}

hello = function(){
    console.log("hello world!");
}

hello(); // hello world!
fnAppend('hello', function(){
    console.log("bye world!");
});
hello(); // hello world! bye world
```

just to show the approach, the function parent `window` can also be an optional argument to the `fnAppend` function. Just changing the order will give you `fnPrepend`

---

EDIT

```
function fnAppend(old_fn_name, new_fn, obj){
    obj = obj || window;
    var old_fn = obj[old_fn_name];
    obj[old_fn_name] = function(){
        old_fn.apply({},arguments);
        new_fn.apply({},arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works for global variables. Which makes it a useless solution because globals should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: this don't work on Node.JS for example because i don't have the Window, that's why i used eval(), do you know if is there something that could replace it?